# Availability of side-by-side line-by-line English-Italian.....opera libretti

Tags: classical-music, opera

We've been taking advantage of the Met Opera's daily showings

[Met Opera viewings](https://www.metopera.org/user-information/nightly-met-opera-streams/week-5/)

--and I particularly enjoy them when I have side-by-side line-by-line English-Italian (French, Russian...) libretti with which to follow along.

I've managed to get such libretti a few times on-line, through murashev.com--but even then not in any particularly systematic manner. So, specifically I'd like such libretti, if available,  for the upcoming Met Opera's viewings, and for operas, in general.

I suspect that in most cases, this will not be doable.

Comment: In principle CD booklets often provide those; some labels even have them downloadable for free. In the era of streaming services this will probably diminish soon. If different cuts are being made, some differences will remain.

Comment: You seem to be experienced enough to realize that only in rare cases will a strictly line by line translation be possible, but others might not be.  For example, a subordinate clause that takes up two lines would normally have the verb in the first of those lines in English but at the end if the second line in German.

Comment: OK, phoog! That's fine in any case. I'm just trying to view these operas in a somewhat more active--rather than passive (not comprehending the sung words by and large) role.

Answer (score 2):

I use [Opera Folio](http://www.operafolio.com/list_of_opera_libretti.asp) as the go-to place to get libretto. They usually have translations of the original text too, if you want to follow along. For some of the older public domain operas, [IMSLP](https://imslp.org/wiki/Main_Page) will have the libretto on their site. Generally, I go for the vocal scores on IMSLP because I like following along with the music. Sometimes the scores have the English translation side-by-side with the original language. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. Will investigate-it's the side-by-side ones I really enjoy. (I have some knowledge of Italian, French and Russian--but it's often hard to discern the sung words--and the side-by-sides help.)  I'll check out the scores too, although I don't read the music itself.

Answer (score 0):

Two other approaches that seem worth pursuing are to: (1)  enter as a search

English-Italian (French,...) libretto opera-in-question murashev.com

and (2) check the external links in the corresponding wikipedia article for the opera in question, the latter approach giving me  English-French side-by-side (termed "Parallel") libretto, courtesy of Project Gutenberg

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Tales_of_Hoffmann